# Why is a larger SSX preferred in a simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model

We had a true-and-false exercise in our linear regression class that stated:

> When designing a study, larger SSX is generally preferred to obtain a more precise estimate.

And the answer is true.

I only know that $SSX = \sum^n_{i=1} (x_i - \bar{x})^2 = (n-1) \widehat{VAR}(x)$. Why would it be better to have a larger SSX?

Comment: This is true *so long as SST doesn't change*. the way to look at it is that SST=SSX+SSE, so the bigger SSX is the smaller SSE is (the more variance is explained by X). If we don't restrict SST to stay the same, it's easy to make SSX very big by measuring $X$ in small units (i.e. micrometers if X is measuring distance), because then each term $x_i-\bar{x}$ will be huge, but this doesn't actually mean we're doing well.

Comment: Look at the formula for the standard error of whatever the "estimate" might be.  Assuming it refers to a parameter estimate with the usual parameterization, $SS_X$ will be in the denominator and the result follows.  That assumption is crucial.  For instance, if the "estimate" concerns the possible curvature of the response (which is done in a standard goodness of fit test), then a different conclusion applies and the answer is false.